# A conditional SQL update statement for two tables at once

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I want to update two tables at once. The code below seems to work fine. However, in some cases, there is no entry in bidGroups which means the entire statement would fail. How can I adjust it so it updates the first bit (watchedItems) and does not try the second part if watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NULL

```
UPDATE watchedItems, bidGroups 
SET watchedItems.won=1, bidGroups.bidGroupQty=bidGroups.bidGroupQty-1 
WHERE watchedItems.id=2 
AND watchedItems.aid=200618152822 
AND bidGroups.bidGroupID=watchedItems.bidGroupID 
AND bidGroups.id=2;
```

I tried this, but the syntax is wrong..

```
UPDATE  watchedItems, bidGroups 
SET watchedItems.won=1, 
CASE WHEN watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NOT NULL THEN bidGroups.bidGroupQty=bidGroups.bidGroupQty-1 
ELSE END
WHERE watchedItems.id=2 
AND watchedItems.aid=200618152822 
AND bidGroups.bidGroupID=watchedItems.bidGroupID 
AND bidGroups.id=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try LEFT JOIN this way:

```
UPDATE watchedItems 
LEFT JOIN bidGroups ON watchedItems.bidGroupID = bidGroups.bidGroupID AND bidGroups.id=2
SET watchedItems.won=1, bidGroups.bidGroupQty=bidGroups.bidGroupQty-1 
WHERE watchedItems.id=2 
AND watchedItems.aid=200618152822;
```

......

Comment: This is it. Works perfectly. Many thanks Abhay. Time for me to learn about JOINs now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `left outer join` is all.

```
update watchedItems wi left outer join bidGroups bg
 on wi.bidGroupID = bg.bidGroupID
 set
  wi.won = 1,
  bg.bidGroupQty = bg.bidGroupQty - 1
 where wi.id = 2
 and wi.aid = 200618152822
 and (bg.id = 2 or bg.id is null)
```

If `watchedItems.bidGroupId` is null, then it will only update the found row in `watchedItems`, since there's nothing to join to in `bidGroups`. If it's not and the join gets rows in both tables, the updates to both tables happen just fine.

Just using `watchedItems, bidGroups` is the same as `inner join`, so when there isn't an entry in `bidGroups` to join to, you also don't get a result from `watchedItems`. Use the same `join` and `where` clauses on a `select` instead of an `update`, and you'll see the difference:

```
select wi.won, bg.bidGroupQty
 from watchedItems wi, bidGroups bg
 where wi.id = 2 and wi.aid = 200618152822
 and (bg.id = 2 or bg.id is null)
 and wi.bidGroupID = bg.bidGroupID
```

vs:

```
select wi.won, bg.bidGroupQty
 from watchedItems wi left outer join bidGroups bg
 on wi.bidGroupID = bg.bidGroupID
 where wi.id = 2 and wi.aid = 200618152822
 and (bg.id = 2 or bg.id is null)
```

Comment: I think this will not work because the condition "bg.id = 2" in the WHERE clause will produce no results if `bidGroups` has no entry for ID = 2; no results will mean no update will run

Comment: Abhay is right. I tried all of them and unfortunately they are accepted syntax-wise but return no results.. Many thanks for your efforts and explanations though, highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Good point. Just need to `OR` with a check against null so it handles the case of no results from the right side. But Abhay's way of putting that condition in the `ON` clause is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

just set it to its current value if you dont want to change. 
And MySQL usually optimises it away by not updating it when the value is same.

```
UPDATE watchedItems 
  LEFT JOIN bidGroups ON bidGroups.bidGroupID=watchedItems.bidGroupID 
       AND bidGroups.id=2
SET watchedItems.won=1, 
    bidGroups.bidGroupQty= if(watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NULL, 
                              bidGroups.bidGroupQty, 
                              bidGroups.bidGroupQty-1)
WHERE watchedItems.id=2 
AND watchedItems.aid=200618152822;
```

however, you dont need the `if` because if `watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NULL` then row from bidGroups is not joined and update for that non-existant row is ignored. 
So `bidGroups.bidGroupQty=bidGroups.bidGroupQty-1` is just fine

Comment: I like the idea. However, when I tried it and there is no entry in the bidGroups table it also does not affect the watchedItems table?! :-(

Comment: The `,` is the same as an `inner join`, that's why. I added some explanation to my answer.