# sql update with joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Say I have this select statement:

```
SELECT ut.user_id,
       a.firstname,
       a.surname,
       u.username,
       u.email_address
  FROM administrators a 
  JOIN user_types ut JOIN users u ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id 
   AND u.user_id = ut.user_id AND ut.user_type = 'ADMIN';
```

Say I wanted to update ALL values in the row where user_id = 1;

I could update EACH TABLE individually OR i could create a view like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW full_admin AS
SELECT ut.user_id,
       a.firstname,
       a.surname,
       u.username,
       u.email_address
  FROM administrators a 
  JOIN user_types ut 
  JOIN users u  on a.admin_id = ut.type_id 
   AND u.user_id = ut.user_id 
   AND ut.user_type = 'ADMIN'
```

Then I could write:

```
UPDATE full_admin
   SET firstname = 'blah', etc, etc
 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

And that will update all rows in all tables

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT creating a view?

Something like:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT ut.user_id,
           a.firstname,
           a.surname,
           u.username,
           u.email_address
      FROM administrators a 
      JOIN user_types ut 
      JOIN users u ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id 
       AND u.user_id = ut.user_id 
       AND ut.user_type = 'ADMIN'
)
AS temp_table
  SET firstname = "ALEX"
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

However that doesnt work

Comment: If you want to update columns in both administrators and users at once then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362594/a-conditional-sql-update-statement-for-two-tables-at-once. If you want to just update columns in administrators based on a join to users then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [update columns in both](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) administrators and users at once, then something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE administrators a  
        INNER JOIN user_types ut ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id 
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ut.user_id 
            SET u.firstname = "ALEX", a.SomeColumn = 'X' 
        WHERE u.user_id = 1 
                 AND ut.user_type = 'ADMIN'
```

The SET statement section can work on any of the columns in the join.

(If that's what you are asking!)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE administrators a 
INNER JOIN user_types ut ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ut.user_id AND ut.user_type = 'ADMIN'
SET u.firstname = "ALEX"
WHERE u.user_id = 1
;
```

Ofcourse this will only work (same thing applies to the view) if the joined table construct is updateable.

Comment: Not all JOINS are updateable, e.g. LEFT JOINS will not work (The DB has no PK to address a row). This is exactly the same for Views.

Answer (score 0):

You may do some scripting (PLSQL) but I don't believe you may update several tables in one SQL query other than through a view.

PLSQL is powerfull and not complicated and can be triggered by database events.